Migration from ANT to Salesforce CLI v2 - Script
Ant gave the possibility of creating a build.xml file which, by calling single operation, performed certain operations, for example:
<target name="retrieveFromDEV">
   <sf:retrieve username="${u.username.dev}" password="${u.password.dev}" sessionId="${u.sessionId}" serverurl="${u.serverurl}" maxPoll= "${u.maxPoll}" pollWaitMillis="${u.pollWaitMillis}" retrieveTarget="retrieve/DEV" unpackaged="retrieve/package.xml"/>
</target>

the "u" values were inside the build.properties file.
With the "ant retrieveFromDEV" command I saw the metadata of the retrieve with respect to the package.xml in the "retrieve/DEV" folder.
How can I create a similar operation in the Salesforce CLI?
There is the possibility of creating a script that with one command carries out:

Login
retrieve based on a package.xml
saving the metadata in a specific folder

Thanks

First, note that logging in is usually a one-step process, rather than something you do each time you run the command. That said, check out sf org command for various login options.
In the general sense, your command is now simply just:
sf project retrieve start -x path/to/package.xml -t metadata-out-dir

This command would be placed into a file appropriate for your shell environment. For Windows Command Line, that is typically a .bat file, Windows PowerShell is a .ps1 file, and most UNIX/Linux-based environments typically use .sh for a shell script.
If you want environment variables, that will also depend on your choice of shell. For example, in Bash, that might look like:
MANIFEST=path/to/package.xml
OUTPUT_DIR=metadata-out-dir
sf project retrieve start -x $MANIFEST -t $OUTPUT_DIR

You can also use variables with VS Code in a NPM project.xml to set up scripts that can be run directly from the IDE. Other IDEs also typically have this capability as well. Different shells have different capabilities, so do check out the relevant documentation.
